# Post Username & Password To Protected Folder/Site

Tags: iis, authentication, password-protection

I'm trying to post a username & password from an HTML form to a protected folder on a website?   Is this possible?  I thought I just pass in a syntax in the URL like the below but not having any success

http://username:password@theurlofthesite.co.uk

I'm still getting the alert pop up asking for the username and password?  I need to be able to auto log the person in..

Hope someone can help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did exactly what I did in the question and it works on all browser except Safari on a Mac

Answer (score 1):

If you login via a HTML form, then this won't work. This is only for HTTP authentication, which is something else completely different.

I don't think many (any?) browsers support being opened to post data. Which leaves you hoping that the site accepts GET based logins (and they should be shot if they do.).

Answer (score 0):

The address part of the URL is parsed by your web server, so the code which handles the HTML form never sees it.

If you want to pass parameters to a form, you must use `url?field=value&field2=value2`. This only works with forms that use the `GET` action. For `POST`, you need a program to generate an encoded document and upload that.

In both cases, your user name and password are broadcasted as plain text on the Internet, so the account will be hacked within a few hours. To put it more clearly: There is no way to "protect" the data in this folder this way. This is like adding a door with four locks to your house and keep the keys on a nail in a post on the street next to the door.